# How can i gain access to the CorsWhitelistEntry object?

Tags: apex, api, object

I'm trying to get all the cors whitelist right when my applications starts uploading and i have no trobule doing so as an admin. The problems appears when i log in a standard user. I'm getting an error in my console saying "sObject type is not supported". Is there a way i can fix this?

This is my where i'm getting the list from

> @AuraEnabled @RemoteAction
>
> public static List getWhitelist() {
>
> try {
>
> List whiteList = [SELECT Id, UrlPattern FROM CorsWhiteListEntry];
>
> updateLastTimeUserEnter();
>
> return whiteList;
>
> } catch (Exception e) {
>
> throw e;
>
> }
>
> }